# Mutex in C# for the same assembly

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mutex

We have an assembly that is called repeatedly by different executables and it shares these states how its like not thread safe because they call the code at same time  what kinda mutex to use

Comment: Sharing an assembly between different applications is not an issue as such. Could you be more descriptive of what your assembly does, e.g. does it use a restricted or limited resource?

Comment: Please learn to used Periods (.), Commas (,), and Captialization (a vs. A) in your posts.  It will make them easier to read, understand, and answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can find your solution described in this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SingleInstanceAppMutex.aspx).